# Applying for Canadian Tourist visa using one-way ticket

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, canada, tourist-visas

I am planning to apply for a Canadian tourist visa but my official leave isn't confirmed yet, so I don't know if I will visit for a month or two. I am thinking to apply for a visa now with a One-way ticket into Canada and then buy a return ticket when my leave is confirmed. Will my chances of visa approval become slim with a one-way ticket? I am an Indian citizen working for an Indian government-owned bank and have never left the country before.

Comment: That is a sure way to get your visa denied. Your chances of getting a Canadian visa are already very low considering you have no international travel experience.

Comment: One way tickets are a huge red flag. Buy a full-price refundable round-trip ticket.

Comment: Also, don't forget that solid ties to your home country are an asset.  If your leave is approved, you have a letter from your employer saying so, and you have a round-trip ticket, this is a huge asset in the application.  Conversely, if you have a one-way ticket and your leave hasn't been approved, the immigration officer is likely to think you don't really care about keeping your job in India, and you're just planning to stay and work illegally in Canada.

Comment: Or wait until your leave is confirmed

Comment: I'm with @Traveller on this, although whether it is practical depends on how long before your trip your leave is likely to be confirmed.

Comment: Don't buy a plane ticket until your visa is approved.

Comment: @MichaelHampton is that even an option? Wouldn't the visa approval depend on a confirmed itinerary?

Comment: @Neels I just went through Canada's visa instructions and document checklist. A plane ticket is not listed on either. What is listed is that you must prove you can afford the trip. Bank statements, a letter from your company if they are paying for the trip, etc. A flight itinerary really proves nothing with regard to visa approval or denial, so it's not common for countries to require it (anymore).

Comment: Yes, I have seen that the plane ticket is not listed! That's why the confusion!

Comment: @MichaelHampton An RT ticket may not be required, but its presence is an indicator that the applicant is more likely to depart after his trip, rather than stay on. A ticket's presence adds weight to the application; it's absence suggests an immigrant intent on the part of the applicant.

Comment: @David Eh? That doesn't make any sense at all. Neither a ticket nor lack of it indicates immigrant intent or its opposite, _before_ receiving a visa. All it indicates, if someone has not bought a ticket before applying for a visa, is that they haven't bought a ticket. That said, some countries explicitly want people to purchase a ticket before applying for a visa; Canada doesn't appear to be among them.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I disagree. (Nothing wrong with that, IMO) An applicant proffering an RT ticket is presenting some evidence of an intent to depart. The Canada visa application might not explicitly require showing an RT ticket, but having one might help address the elephant in the room. I'd conclude differently if the visa application contained language like "Because your visa application may be denied, do not buy your ticket until a visa has been issued."

Comment: @David In most cases and for many countries, that is exactly the advice given to visa applicants. In the absence of official advice to the contrary, it's also a good idea not to buy tickets. Again, possessing tickets proves nothing above not possessing them, at the visa application stage. It means nothing to not have a ticket before applying for a visa; the idea that _not_ having a ticket to travel somewhere indicates immigrant intent is so absurd on its face, that it hardly needs any further discussion. I haven't bought a ticket to India, but I don't wish to immigrate there...